# Google Android Fragmentation: Inconsistent CSS Rendering

Tags: android, css, webkit

Working on a mobile web application, I have found that some Android devices are rendering CSS differently than others. The detail on the site renders perfectly on every desktop browser I have tried on Windows & Mac, on iPhone, on every Android SDK Emulator I have tried, and even BlackBerry. While some Android devices render it perfectly, about half do not - and these "misrender" it in consistent ways. (For example, it looks great in a Galaxy, but is offset when using a G2.)

Aside from purchasing every single Android device on the market, is there any way to test CSS across all the devices available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you looked at the Android version number for each of the devices you're talking about? Android has gone through a number of revisions, but some manufacturers are still shipping older versions. There *shouldn't* be significant CSS variations between devices running on the same Android version, but from one version to another anything could have happened. (having said that, most of the android manufacturers like to tweak the OS themselves, so I can't rule out any CSS differences within a single android version, but even then there shouldn't be anything huge)

Comment: if it is related to the android version, as I suspect, then the android emulator does allow you to test each released version.

Comment: Spudley, I didn't give the emulator enough credit. Thanks for encouraging me to recheck my settings. Got it! Now the easy part: FIXING it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact: you can use the emulator to replicate CSS differences. I didn't try enough variations.